# Graphics card array to output array - use switch?

Tags: ubuntu, bash, multiple-monitors, graphics-card, switch

I have **3** graphics cards in my Ubuntu 10.04 server machine. I also have **7** monitors. I would like to take an input (a media file), play it on one of the graphics cards, and then be able to programmatically select which monitor to play the media on.

Is there a hardware switch I can buy that will facilitate this? Basically whatever it is should take at least 3 inputs (for graphics cards) and have at least 6 ports going out (for monitor) and be able to programmatically select which output to play on.

Any ideas on a hardware switch?

Comment: Can you not just add more graphics outputs to the machine?

Comment: @Shinrai no. the other slots in the motherboard are all taken.

Comment: I figured, hence my use of 'outputs' rather than 'cards'.  Swap cards for higher density ones; you could make do with two quad output cards for 7 monitors, or if you currently have three dual output cards just change one to a triple or quad output.  This seems like it would probably be just as expensive but probably much easier to work with (and has the benefit of not requiring additional external hardware/cable mess).

Comment: @Shinrai, no that is not what I want. the outputs I am using are 50 in+ in size, I am playing hi-def movies, and no graphics card in the world can thread well enough to play them simultaneously. so back to the hardware switch...?

Comment: There are plenty of cards that can handle that, but they'd be expensive ones (and the machine itself might not be able to handle it).  The extra context is useful though, thanks; I agree that you might be better off with an external solution.  Unfortunately, I don't know of one myself.